# Using BETO - Spanish version BERT

Tags: python, tensorflow, multilingual, text-classification, bert-language-model

I'm trying to build a Spanish text classifier based on BERT. So I selected a model called BETO https://github.com/scruz03/beto. I am working on Google Colab and trying to replicate the steps indicated in the example cited at the same page referred before https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1uRwg4UmPgYIqGYY4gW_Nsw9782GFJbPt#scrollTo=HhAqZLs3lwhW.
I did download the uncased tensorflow version instead of the pytorch one mentioned in the example. I got the following files in the tensorflow subdirectory:

[image]

However, when I ran the following code:

```
# create the tokenizer and the model
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("tensorflow/")
model = BertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained("tensorflow/")
model.eval()
```

I got the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-4b5a17f4238d> in <module>()
      1 # create the tokenizer and the model
      2 tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("tensorflow/")
----> 3 model = BertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained("tensorflow/")
      4 model.eval()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args, **kwargs)
    982                         "Error no file named {} found in directory {} or `from_tf` set to False".format(
    983                             [WEIGHTS_NAME, TF2_WEIGHTS_NAME, TF_WEIGHTS_NAME + ".index"],
--> 984                             pretrained_model_name_or_path,
    985                         )
    986                     )

OSError: Error no file named ['pytorch_model.bin', 'tf_model.h5', 'model.ckpt.index'] found in directory tensorflow/ or `from_tf` set to False
```

I would appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you are getting an error is that you are trying to load a tensorflow model to a class that expects pytorch model.

Huggingface API provies a tensorflow equivalent class.

To use it, instead of `BertForMaskedLM` use `TFBertForMaskedLM`

Comment: Thanks. I did implement the change you suggested. The error changed a bit to `Error no file named ['pytorch_model.bin', 'tf_model.h5'] found in directory TensorFlow/ or from_pt set to False`. Not sure where the tf_model.h5 is. I imagine it could be obtained from the files in the TensorFlow subdirectory.

Comment: I did solve the remaining problem. It was due to the directory I did enter `tensorflow/` which was where I got the files at Colab. However, the function was expecting something different: `from_pretrained ("dccuchile/bert-base-spanish-wwm-uncased", from_pt=True)`. This was enough to solve this issue. The path was already specified in the original BETO description at Github.